# How do I change the width of dashboard in GNOME?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-tweak-tool

Trying to make few customization to Ubuntu GNOME and I am already surprised to see the flexibility and option to customize Ubuntu.

I have already installed Dash to Dock and Tweak Tool, but I could not find an option to increase the width of the Dashboard that contains all the application.

I might be looking for the wrong keyword as I could not find any solution on Google and Ask Ubuntu.

Screenshot of the Dashboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try the "[More columns in applications view](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1305/more-columns-in-applications-view/)" GNOME shell extension. It lets you

> Set the number of columns in the "applications" view (by default, the maximum is only 6)

and thus you would be able to use those empty spaces.

Refer to this to learn how to install and manage GNOME shell extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)